# How to make a game inventory store items in the order they were recieved?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, insert

I'm in the process of making a text-based adventure game with a working GUI. The GUI is already is complete and the story is close to being done, so I'm just making little tweaks to try and improve it.

[image]

Right now, I have an inventory [*on the right*] where new items are added when they are picked up. It consists of disabled entry boxes, which are enabled when an item is about to be added to them / deleted from them and then disables again.

If you were to pick up a rope, the code looks something like this:

```
rope = 0

#The next part isn't actually in a separate `def` in my full code, it is a part of the same `def` which also loads the text
def addRope():
    global rope
    rope = 1
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item2TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item2TextBox.insert(0, 'Rope')
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='disabled')
```

The `rope = 0` is a check if the user has the item on them when they could use it. As in I use `if` / `elif` / `else` to check if the item is set to 0 or 1.

Right now, I made it so each item the user can get along the way wouldn't inserted into the same text box as another item. To be more precise, I went through the story and checked of the user would have an item in that spot of the inventory when they would gain a new item. If the answer is a definite no, I would use that slot and if the answer is yes or possibly I would check the next slot down and so on. I'm doing this manually and not by code.

This system mainly works, but there parts of the story where the user may keep or loose an item depending on their choice. So the answer to my question is there is an item in the text box is possibly meaning I use the next box down. But this lead to scenarios where there is an empty box but the item is entered into the box below it. [*There is an example of this below*]

[image]

**What I need:**
I need a system which checks if the inventory slot is empty, inserts the text into it and them **remembers in which box the item was inserted** so when the user looses or discards the item, it is deleted from their inventory. Has anyone got an idea of how this may work?

I've included a modified code down below to replicate what I currently have done:

```
from tkinter import *

#This is the GUI
GUI = Tk()
GUI.geometry('500x300')
GUI.title("Login Screen")

#These are the entry boxes. They all disabled.
ItemsLabel = Label(GUI, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), text='Inventory:', bg='black', fg='white', bd=5, justify=LEFT)
ItemsLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
Item1TextBox = Entry(GUI, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='#7501A5', fg='Black', bd=5, width=20, borderwidth=4,
                     justify=CENTER)
Item1TextBox.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10)
Item1TextBox.configure(state="disabled")
Item2TextBox = Entry(GUI, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='#7501A5', fg='Black', bd=5, width=20, borderwidth=4,
                     justify=CENTER)
Item2TextBox.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10)
Item2TextBox.configure(state="disabled")
Item3TextBox = Entry(GUI, font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), bg='#7501A5', fg='Black', bd=5, width=20, borderwidth=4,
                     justify=CENTER)
Item3TextBox.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
Item3TextBox.configure(state="disabled")

#These are the items the user can get.
item1 = 0
item2 = 0
item3 = 0

#This adds Item 1 and 2 into the top two entry boxes.
def addItem1Item2():
    global item1, item2
    item2 = 1
    item1 = 1
    Item1TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item1TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item1TextBox.insert(0, 'Item 1')
    Item1TextBox.configure(state='disabled')
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item2TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item2TextBox.insert(0, 'Item 2')
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='disabled')

#This removes Item 1 and 2 from the top two boxes.
def removeItem1Item2():
    global item1, item2
    item2 = 0
    item1 = 0
    Item1TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item1TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item1TextBox.configure(state='disabled')
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item2TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item2TextBox.configure(state='disabled')

#This adds Item 3 into the bottom entry box.
def addItem3():
    global item3
    item3 = 1
    Item3TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item3TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item3TextBox.insert(0, 'Item 3')
    Item3TextBox.configure(state='disabled')

#This removes Item 3 from the bottom box.
def removeItem3():
    global item3
    item3 = 0
    Item3TextBox.configure(state='normal')
    Item3TextBox.delete(0, END)
    Item3TextBox.configure(state='disabled')

#These are the buttons.
button1 = Button(GUI, command=addItem1Item2, text='Add Item 1 and Item 2')
button1.grid()

button2 = Button(GUI, command=addItem3, text='Add Item 3')
button2.grid()

button3 = Button(GUI, command=removeItem1Item2, text='Remove Item 1 a Item 2')
button3.grid()

button4 = Button(GUI, command=removeItem3, text='Remove Item 3')
button4.grid()

GUI.mainloop()
```

Can anyone think of a solution to so the items are always inserted into the first empty slot and then deleted from the correct box?

Comment: I would say to append these entries to list, so now they have index number and do the inserting.

Comment: @CoolCloud , I've only started to learn python last month, so I'm not quite sure how to do your suggestion. I would appreciate an example of this, or if not, could you link me to tutorial or explanation of what you suggested?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you included?